# Why phpMyAdmin is not importing my table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm a designer, but as there's no programmer in my company I have to start studing programming. Which I did only somedays ago (and I have only  a html and css knowledge background) so pleasepleaseplease don't take any knowledge for granted if you can answer me!

I'm studing PHP and MySQL using "PHP & MySQL in easy steps" by Mike McGranth (if any of you have it I'm at page 90/91). So, the task is simple: write a .sql file and create a table in phpMyAdmin with it.
Since it's an exercise from a book I just have to write as it's written on the page and test it; yes, I have the solution-file too, but the point is I can't see the difference between my code, which can't be processed by phpMyAdmin, and the solution-code, which gives no problem.

The .sql file written by me is this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products
(
id INT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT ,
code INT NOT_NULL ,
name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL ,
quantity INT DEFAULT 1 NULL ,
price DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL
) ;
```

And the solution-file code is this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products
(
  id        INT UNIQUE  AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  code      INT     NOT NULL ,
  name      VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL ,
  quantity  INT     DEFAULT 1 NULL , 
  price     DECIMAL(6,2)    NOT NULL
) ;
```

This is also how the look like in a code-editor program:
[image]

This is the error that phpMyAdmin gives to me (if the japanese part is important I can add the translation):
[image]

Since I have a solution, why do I ask? Because maybe I've done just a small mistake, but if I don't understand it I'm afraid to do it again when handling bigger files, maybe a client db, real work, not just an exercise.
So, if anyone will be so kind to explain it to me he/she will have my ethernal gratitude!

Comment: You should include your error message in your question, preferably as the text rather than an off-site screenshot.

Comment: If i am not wrong, you didnt create the database but trying to create table. Have you got your database named.

Comment: The database was already created to do other exercises ^^
pvg : next time I will do it (if I manage to understand how, I clicked so many things when writing but I couldn't find a good way to post the text) thnak you all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update this cause `NOT_NULL` is not correct

```
code INT NOT_NULL ,
```

to

```
code INT NOT NULL ,
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wrote NOT NULL so many times, how come I wrote NOT_NULL once and I couldn't even see it? Thank you!

Comment: its ok , this is sometime mistake but i answered first so you do not accept my answer. by the way its ok. carry on

Comment: Sorry! I thought the answer on the top was the fastest!

Comment: its ok man. feeling happy and i was first . happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove underscore from NOT_NULL in the code column. So replace

```
code INT NOT_NULL ,
```

To

```
code INT NOT NULL ,
```

Comment: It was a super stupid error! Thank you for the kind reply!

Comment: It's okay. It happens sometime. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is

```
code INT NOT_NULL
```

That underscore is wrong .

If you take a look at other lines in your sql, you'll see others NOT NULL fields without underscore.

That's the difference between your code and solution.

Comment: And I checked it so many times! How stupid! Thank you so much!!